# Updating sql record based on 2 values in table

Tags: sql, sql-update, max

I have a table that has the following columns:

```
GRVLID
GRID
Timein
Timeout
```

This table is part of a visitor tracking system.

There is another table that holds each visitor's information. *This* table keeps track of each time the visitor logs in and out.

`GRVLID` is the unique record identifier. `GRID` is the visitor identifier number. Each visitor has their own `GRID` number. `Timein` is the datetime when the visitor logged in. `Timeout` is the datetime when the visitor logged out.

Every time a visitor logs in, a new record is created. So it would be possible to have multiple records with the same `GRID` number. The `GRVLID` number is unique and just increments as new records are added.

What I need is an update-set-where statement that updates the record that has the highest `GRVLID` number for a given `GRID` number.  I tried doing:

```
update database
set [TimeOut] = @p_timeOut
where (GRID = @p_GRID and MAX(GRVLID))
```

but that doesn't seem to play nice with `MSSQL`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is more like this:

```
update database
set [TimeOut] = @p_timeOut
where GRID = @p_GRID 
and GRVLID = (select MAX(GRVLID) from database WHERE where GRID = @p_GRID)
```

There are more efficient ways to re-write this query, but if performance isn't a concern then this will work fine and it's easy to understand.

P.S. I hope your table really isn't named "database".

Comment: Fantastic.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.  And no, my table really isn't named "database".

Answer (score 0):

Possibly like this:

```
update database
set [TimeOut] = @p_timeOut
from database
where GRVLID in
(select max(GRVLID) from database group by GRID)
```

With `select max(GRVLID) from database group by GRID` you select the max value of `GRVLID` for each `GRID`.

Afterwords, you `update` the rows that have the `GRVLID` selected.